# Value Paste Google Sheets to new Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As you may realise from my attempt below, google scripts is not my greatest strength.
All our school rewards/sanctions currently go into a google sheet. at the end of each term I would like to archive a number of those sheets into a new workbook/spreadsheet.  When this happens they need to value copies only.
I can get this code working for any individual sheet but am not very familiar with the for loop so cannot achieve this for all four sheets together.
Grateful for any help you experts might be able to offer!
`

```js
> function copySheetValues()
{
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = ['tally', 'commendations', 'detentions', 'omegas'];
  for (var i=0, i<3, i++)
    var sheet = source.getSheetByName(sheetname[i]);
    sheet.activate();
  var sourcename = sheet.getSheetName();
  var sourceDataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var sourceSheetValues = sourceDataRange.getValues();
  var sourceRows = sourceDataRange.getNumRows();
    var sourceColumns = sourceDataRange.getNumColumns();
  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create('Archive');
  var url = (ssNew.getUrl());
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  

  destination.insertSheet(sourcename, 0);
  destination.getDataRange().offset(0, 0, sourceRows, sourceColumns).setValues(sourceSheetValues);
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

using a different approach, can you see if this works for you ?

```
function backup() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var bs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss.copy('Archive').getId());
var sheets = ['tally', 'commendations', 'detentions', 'omegas'];
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
var bsl = bs.getSheets().forEach( function (s) {
if(sheets.indexOf(s.getName()) !== -1) {
s.getDataRange().copyTo(s.getDataRange(), {
            contentsOnly: true
        });
} else {
bs.setActiveSheet(s);
bs.deleteActiveSheet();
}
});
}
```